# cannot load such file - Nokogiri rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I wrote a Ruby script in which I use Nokogiri.

For Rails I made this module in the `lib/` directory:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require 'nokogiri'

Module gk_CT

class CT

  def getCT
    uri = URI.parse("http://www.website.com")
    CT = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

    proc = Nokogiri::HTML(CT.body)

    CTQ = Array.new

    CTQ << proc.css('td')

  end

end
```

In the controller I have:

```
require 'gk_CT'

  def show
    @CT= gk_CT::CT.getCT()
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @CT}
    end
  end
```

It always gives me the error:

```
cannot load such file -- nokogiri
```

and I have no idea why.

Comment: on which line and in which file is the error thrown? if it is CT, it is probably because nokogiri is missing from you `Gemfile`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the script is part of an actual Rails project, then you need to add Nokogiri to the Gemfile   (with the line `gem 'nokogiri'`). If you're not in a Rails project or aren't using Bundler or some such weird thing, you'll still need to install the gem (`gem install nokogiri`).

Comment: I assume you only need to do this if you created the project before installing the gem?

Comment: @JeffAxelrod Not sure exactly what you're asking, but I think you do still need to include a gem in the Gemfile to use it, even if it's already installed.

Comment: When you create the project in Rails, it doesn't automatically add all of your installed gems to the Gemfile?